# Issue on Installing Anaconda for Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda

I installed Anaconda 3 (Python 3.7.3 64-bit) from file `Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe` but I can't find Anaconda Navigator between my desktop apps. I followed some (very) similar questions on this forum but, e.g. after having opened the command terminal and dialed the command:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

I obtained the error text:

```
'anaconda-navigator' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows 10 64x, the only way to make it work was by uninstalling python and anaconda and installing the anaconda 86x.